# How to change an error message given by ParamFetcher?

Tags: php, validation, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

Validation with ParamFetcher is very elegant but error messages is not pretty. It contains many unnecessary information which I don't want to show to api users.

For example:

> "Query parameter parent_id value 'a' violated a constraint (Query
>   parameter value 'a', does not match requirements '\d+')"

**I want to convert this message to more simple message** like: "parent_id must be an integer"

How can I do it?

Code which gives an error is below. And I don't see any way to give another error messages.

**Maybe there is an another alternative for validation query parameters.**

```
$constraint = new Regex(array(
         'pattern' => '#^'.$config->requirements.'$#xsu',
         'message' => sprintf(
                    "%s parameter value '%s', does not match requirements '%s'",
                    $paramType,
                    $param,
                    $config->requirements
         ),
));
```

Source Code:  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamFetcher.php#L220

Comment: If I remember, you can use a custom constraint in the `requirements` part. Try your own `Regex` class prefixed with '@'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a pull request to FOSRestBundle to solve this problem https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/1015

You can use it as shown below

```
@QueryParam(name="parent_id", requirements={"rule" = "\d+", "error_message" = "parent_id must be an integer"}, strict=true, nullable=true, description="Parent Id")
```

Error Message:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "parent_id must be an integer"
}
```